# Rail Library - Setup a Train programmatically

Tags: anylogic

Usually the Train Source is being used to setup a train and its rail cars.

But in my case I want to do it programmatically.
Is there a way I can create a new train, set the number of rail cars, add train to custom population, setup the cars, add the cars to a custom population ect.

The reason for this is, that initially I have to work with the train as a logical agent and set some variables of the trains.

I already tried to create a train programmatically with:

Train train = new Train();

But I couldn´t find any methods or variables to setup the train.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please read [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). "please help me" is [not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question); we don't write code to specification. [You are expected to study the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) ahead of time; think of logical steps to solve the problem; figure out exactly where you are stuck, and be able to show exact input and output.

Comment: Well, he tried and couldn't find any methods, so fair enough imo. @anoj, do read the links above and this one specifically for AnyLogic users: SOF requires a specific way of asking questions: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-community

Answer (score 0):

Never create agents using `new xyz...()` unless you now 100% what you do.

For your problem, there are tons of different solutions such as:

1. use a Java Class object, fill it with your fields and only instantiate a train from it when needed
2. Use the TrainSource with the `inject()` function (Arrivals defined by "calls of inject() function): you can fill the parameters after calling `inject` using the `set_myParameterXYZ(...)` calls on each parameter
3. Create normal agents with a normal `Source` block and convert it to a train manually later

All of these require a bit of coding, there is no pre-set way. But your approach is good: only instantiate a train right when you need it, they are computationally fairly demanding